# Starting a Ventura installer on Sonoma

Tags: macos, install, downgrade, sonoma

I need to install Ventura to a second partition while on Sonoma. My current environment restricts me to a Mac and internet access (no suitable USB drive).

I have downloaded the installer from the App Store. However, when I try to start it, there's an error "This installer cannot be used on your macOS version" with a link to Apple's Support article [Create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). I don't have a drive, so this is pretty much useless.

The question is: can I force-start the installer? The only feature I need is to install macOS on an existing partition. Maybe there's a patched version to use?

Comment: What model/year Mac? Can you post the output from `diskutil list`?